# Limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I've been working on a problem related to convergence of sequences. Specifically, I need to prove that if $a_1, a_2, a_3,... $ is a sequence of real numbers with $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} |a_j|< \infty$ then $lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} a_j$ exists.

I started out using the partial sum approach. Let the partial sum $s_n = \sum^{n}_{j=1} a_j$. Then for $m\leq n $,

$$|s_n - s_m| =| \sum^{n}_{j=1} a_j - \sum^{m}_{j=1} a_j|=| \sum^{n}_{j=m} a_j | \leq \sum^{n}_{j=m} |a_j|$$

I know I'm then supposed to use the fact that $\sum |a_j|$ converges to finish the proof, but am having trouble with the next step.

Comment: The limit is in fact $0$ because $\lim s_n=\lim s_{n-1}$.

Comment: What does $\lim_{N\to\infty}a_j$ mean? $a_j$ does not depend on $N$, so $\lim_{N\to\infty}a_j=a_j$.

Comment: Just for the sake of intuition: Try to imagine a stack of infinitely many books with width $a_j$ that does not decrease to $0$. Your stack would then skyrocket to infinity right? In order to have enough space for your infinitely many books on your shelf you need them to get smaller and smaller in width.

Answer (score 1):

We will prove that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0$.

We know that
$$\forall \epsilon \ \exists N \ \sum_{i=n}^{m}|a_i| < \epsilon, \ n>N, m>N$$.

Therefore,

$$\forall \epsilon \ \exists N \ |a_n|\leq\sum_{i=n}^{m}|a_i| < \epsilon,\ n>N$$,

which is the definition of $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0$.